# How to implement a Sign in function by using Gigya API in JAVA?

Tags: java, gigya

I am trying to delete the accounts from Gigya DB, so we can reuse them to test our login function through Gigya. It seems the UID required for deletion come from login, so how am I suppose to do it in Java?

Comment: Gigya has a Java SDK.
http://developers.gigya.com/030_Server_SDKs/Java

Comment: I looked at it, but I could not figure out how to retrieve the UID which I would like to use to delete an existing account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Ilan, firstly you'll need to include the Gigya Java SDK.

You can then look up the UID using either the Identity Access or Identity Query Tool within Gigya console and use the follow code to delete the account:

```
// delete user record
GSRequest deleteAccountRequest = new GSRequest(apiKey, secretKey, "accounts.deleteAccount");
//deleteAccountRequest.setAPIDomain("eu1.gigya.com");  // enable this if you're using the EU data centre
deleteAccountRequest.setUseHTTPS(true);
deleteAccountRequest.setParam("UID", uid);
GSResponse deleteAccountResponse = deleteAccountRequest.send();
if(deleteAccountResponse.getErrorCode()==0)
{     
} 
else 
{  
    System.out.println("deleteAccountResponse failure: " + deleteAccountResponse.getLog());
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to delete users in batch, you can run a search using accounts.search and delete all the users within the results set:

```
int limit = 100;
String query = "select UID from accounts where ... " + limit; // add your query here i.e. email = 'someone@example.com'
String cursorId = ""; 
int objectsCount = limit;

GSRequest searchRequest;
ArrayList<String> uidList = new ArrayList<String>();

// send request
do 
{
    // check if we have an open cursor
    if(cursorId.length() > 0)
    {
        // run next request in cursor

        // set up request
        searchRequest = new GSRequest(apiKey, secretKey, "accounts.search");
        //searchRequest.setAPIDomain("eu1.gigya.com");
        //searchRequest.setUseHTTPS(true);

        // set timeout
        searchRequest.setParam("timeout", 60000);

        // set cursor id
        searchRequest.setParam("cursorId", cursorId);
    } else {
        // run new request and open cursor

        // set up request
        searchRequest = new GSRequest(apiKey, secretKey, "accounts.search");
        //searchRequest.setAPIDomain("eu1.gigya.com");
        //searchRequest.setUseHTTPS(true);

        // set timeout
        searchRequest.setParam("timeout", 60000);

        // set query
        searchRequest.setParam("query", query);

        // open cursor
        searchRequest.setParam("openCursor", true);
    }

    GSResponse searchResponse = searchRequest.send();
    if(searchResponse.getErrorCode()==0)
    {     
        GSArray uids = new GSArray();
        uids = searchResponse.getArray("results", uids);
        for(int i=0; i<uids.length(); i++)
        {
            String uid;
            try {
                // retrieve uid and add to list of uids
                uid = uids.getObject(i).getString("UID");
                uidList.add(uid);

            } catch (GSKeyNotFoundException e) {
            }

        }

        cursorId = searchResponse.getString("nextCursorId", "");
        objectsCount = searchResponse.getInt("objectsCount", 0);
    } 
    else 
    {  
        System.out.println("searchRequest failure: " + searchResponse.getLog());
    } 
} 
while (objectsCount >= limit);

for(int i=0; i<uidList.size(); i++)
{
    String uid;
    try {
        uid = uidList.get(i);

        // delete user record
        GSRequest deleteAccountRequest = new GSRequest(apiKey, secretKey, "accounts.deleteAccount");
        //deleteAccountRequest.setAPIDomain("eu1.gigya.com");
        deleteAccountRequest.setUseHTTPS(true);
        deleteAccountRequest.setParam("UID", uid);
        GSResponse deleteAccountResponse = deleteAccountRequest.send();
        if(deleteAccountResponse.getErrorCode()==0)
        {     
        } 
        else 
        {  
            System.out.println("deleteAccountResponse failure: " + deleteAccountResponse.getLog());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! The account delete works like a charm. The account.search, I got ErrorCode: 500000
ErrorMsg: java.net.UnknownHostException: account.us1.gigya.com, I check the doc: http://developers.gigya.com/037_API_reference/020_Accounts/accounts.search, it seems need validation the account which requires UID, it is interesting APIs. Also, the account.login cannot get the openID provider's account logged in without user interaction, so I have no way to get the UID by the API. I have to get it from the admin console which I dont like :(, is there a way to get it through API?

Comment: Hi Steve, are you able to share your API key with me so that I can check our logs? The accounts.search method should work and is really the only method to retrieve the UID without requiring the user to login.